# How to solve the definition of dependences with lazy loading js module (file)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, lazy-loading, es6-modules

I have TypeScript with External modules (ES6 modules), that is resolved and compiled by the webpack and ts-loader in es5 bundle.

And also I have separate modules (usually it's file with class), which may extend, patch and add functionality to main bundle, so these separate modules import dependencies from main bundle.

BUT, **these separate modules can be created any time and get to the server any anytime (compiled .js --> upload --> server)** so main bundle doesn't know anything about them.

**How to implement this?** Require.ensure unsuitable, forwarding all the dependencies from **window** very uncomfortable, including for developing.

**P.S.:** Previously, the problem was solved very simply by Internal modules (global namepsaces) and concatenating files in bundle. Any module(object) was available from the **window**, so by native lazy loading (ajax script) could extend, patch and add functionality to bundle.

Comment: For now best solution: `DllPlugin / DllReferencePlugin` + `NamedModulesPlugin`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`DllPlugin / DllReferencePlugin` + `NamedModulesPlugin`